# PyQt5 module cant be found after installing PyQt5 with Installer

Tags: qt, pyqt5

i used the binary installer to install pyqt5
and i have both Qt5 and 5.1 and python versions 2.1 , 2.7 and 3.3 
i installed the PyQt5 in python33 folder as requested but it cant find PyQt5 .
when i try to run any script which uses PyQt5 its says PyQt5 Module was not found.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the python3.3 interpreter and not python2.7 when this happens? The installer only installs it for python3.3 (there's currently no binary installer for python2.x available on the download page). Also, the binary version already comes with it's own version of Qt integrated, installing Qt5 separately isn't needed (unless you want to compile PyQt5 from source).

Comment: Have you checked PYTHONPATH environment variable?  Try including the following:

%PYTHON_HOME%\Lib\site-packages

Make sure you restart any command windows and applications after this change so they pick up the new variable.