# Can't get PyQt5 running

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

i downloaded this:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.6/

and when running any example scripts, I get a `module not found` error like this:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\examples\dialogs\classwizard\classwizard.py", line 45, in <module>
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, QFile, QRegExp
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.`
```

I read this post and added the env variable:
[PyQt5 module cant be found after installing PyQt5 with Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296410/pyqt5-module-cant-be-found-after-installing-pyqt5-with-installer)

Could it be because I am using Python 3.6.5. and the installer is for Python 3.5 ? or do I have to install anything additional? I doubt that because the installer said it installs PyQt, Qt and other tools.

Comment: Your error seems to indicate that you did not have a DLL required by pyqt5. And seem to be a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DLL load failed when importing PyQt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863505/dll-load-failed-when-importing-pyqt5)

Comment: actually, after checking - i do already have the python3.dll that is mentioned in this post

Comment: But did you install Qt? https://www.qt.io/download

Comment: uh, not on its own, but the installer i linked above said that Qt is included

Comment: @FlyingThunder. You cannot mix python versions like that - everything has to match.

Comment: ah, the newest `https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/PyQt-5.10.1/` is for 3.6.5? theres no python version number on it - alright, thanks, i thought it was backwards compatible